# Lasso Regression with specific constraint on each coefficients in Python

Tags: python, linear-regression, lasso-regression

I'm currently running a Lasso regression on a dataset in Python, and need to put constraints on each weight.
I've found something similar but it was on regular Linear regression.
such as scipy.optimize.lsq_linear package.

But any ideas on how to do this on Lasso or Ridge regression?

Comment: Are you using a framework? You don't mention in your question what implementation of Lasso you're using.

Comment: I think you are referring to (adaptive lasso) where you can apply separate penalty factor for each variable. In R this can be done easily using the glmnet package. Check this https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/alasso However, I have not seen an implementation in python for this as yet. Mutar package https://pypi.org/project/mutar/ might be an option but I did not personally try it.

Comment: @PirateNinjas Yeah, sorry, i was using Python for this question

Comment: @smiling4ever yeah, sorry wasn't being clear, i was using this in Python

Comment: What library? SciKit Learn?

Comment: @PirateNinjas Sklearn doesn't have this function

Comment: When you say "Sklearn doesn't have this function", what do you mean? That sklearn lasso doesn't have what you want or that sklearn doesn't implement lasso? Lasso is available in sklearn - see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html